# Is there a way to get the data from the actuator metrics without exposing it to the web?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I've included the necessary dependencies and when it is exposed, I can get the process uptime of my server but I would rather not expose these endpoints to the web for security reasons.  I understand I could use spring security to lock down these endpoints but I would rather not include a dependency that is unnecessary unless its needed.  This is all in a microservice that simply runs a scheduled task.  None of it should be exposed to the web to begin with but since we were using spring boot and needed to collect metrics on it anyways, I decided to go this route.  I'm using spring boot 2.7.16

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.16</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
```

Here is the scrubbed code I'm using.  @Autowired works fine when the metrics endpoint is exposed to the web

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private MetricsEndpoint metrics;

        @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${schedule.checkAvailability}")
    public void checkUptime() {
        Set<String> listOfNames = metrics.listNames().getNames();
        LOGGER.info("Trying to log list of names");
        LOGGER.info(listOfNames);
        listOfNames.forEach(names -> {
            LOGGER.info(names);
        });
        // this returns the amount of time the JVM has been active in seconds
        Double uptimeInSeconds = metrics.metric("process.uptime", null).getMeasurements().get(0).getValue();
        LOGGER.info("uptimeInSeconds");
        LOGGER.info(uptimeInSeconds);
        }
```

I'm using fabric8 in order download configMaps and apply them on start.  Its worked perfectly in that regard and when I enable the web endpoint this all works. Here is my scrubbed config map

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
    name: example
data:
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: "health,info"
    management.endpoints.web.base-path: "/example/metrics/actuator"
    management.metrics.enable.all: "true"
    #time in milliseconds
    schedule.checkAvailability: "60000"
```

I've tried just making my own MetricsEndpoint bean with a SimpleMeterRegistry but this does not seem to be giving any metrics at all.  When I log the list of names available for metrics, its empty.  I'd prefer to somehow use the default metrics provided when its exposed to the web as the information seems valuable for our use case.

```
    @Bean
    public MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint() {
        SimpleMeterRegistry registery = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
        return new MetricsEndpoint(registery);
    }
```

UPDATE SOLVED
For the poor soul who finds this via google.
I did this with JMX.
Im not sure if there is an easier and better way but its how I made it work.
I kept the logging in but feel free to remove it obviously.
I'm using the jackson mapper com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
If you want to define your own domain here is a link https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-jmx.html
I just defined my own in my configMap and included the
spring.jmx.enabled: "true" as well.

```
    private ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> getMetricMeasurements(String metric) throws Exception {
        Object individualMetric = null;
        Map<String, Object> metricMap = null;
        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName metricsName = null;
        MBeanInfo mBeanInfo = null;
        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> measurementList = null;

        try {
            LOGGER.info("looking at metricsObject");
            //this will be either the default spring domain or your defined one
            metricsName = new ObjectName("org.springframework.boot:type=Endpoint,name=Metrics");
            LOGGER.info(metricsName);
            LOGGER.info("looking at mBeanInfo");
            mBeanInfo = mBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(metricsName);
            LOGGER.info(mBeanInfo);

            if (mBeanInfo != null) {
                try {
                    Object[] metricParam = { metric };
                    String[] metricSignature = { String.class.getName(), List.class.getName() };
                    LOGGER.info("looking at individualMetric");
                    individualMetric = mBeanServer.invoke(metricsName, "metric", metricParam, metricSignature);
                    LOGGER.info(individualMetric);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            if (individualMetric != null) {
                ObjectMapper JSONMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                String jsonString = JSONMapper.writeValueAsString(individualMetric);
                LOGGER.info("metricMap");
                metricMap = JSONMapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
                LOGGER.info(metricMap);
                LOGGER.info("measurementList");
                measurementList = (ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>) metricMap.get("measurements");
                LOGGER.info(measurementList);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        return measurementList;
    }
```

This will return the following format if you call getMetricMeasurement("process.uptime")
[{statistic=VALUE, value=some-double-value}]